# The rule of the slack variable in an indicator constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, indicator-constraints

In some cases I have seen, the indicator constraint can be written as `indcons(expression, binary_var)`. Then it is interpreted as follows:

$$LHS - slack (\leq = \geq) RHS$$
$$ if: \quad (binary = 1) \implies (slack = 0)$$

As far as I know, CPLEX and maybe Gurobi have used binary variables and whose linking to linearize the constraint. I am actually not aware of their internal mechanism. Now, I would like to know the rule of the slack variable in this form and if is it necessary to use that instead of using e.g. $BigM$ approach.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I can only tell you that SAS supports the `y=1 implies sum {j in JSET} a[j]*x[j] <= b` form, where the `y=1` could instead be `y=0` and the constraint could instead be `>=` or `=` or a range or linearizable.  Under the hood, a big-M formulation is used.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, Thanks for mentioning that.